# Работа с видео на веб-странице

Tags: веб-программирование, html5

При загрузке веб-страницы необходимо, чтоб видео автоматически было загружено, начиная с половины полной продолжительности. Необходимо использовать тег `<video>`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с помощью чего можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать 2 пути, с `JS` и без.

Без `JS`:

Добавьте к URL `#t=[(start_time), (end_time)]`. Но тут надо знать время начала и конца видео. Не поддерживается в IE.

```
<video id="video">
    <source src="video.mp4#t=12,30" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

С `JS`:

Время указывается в секундах от начала ролика.

```
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  this.currentTime = 5;
}, false);
```